# Getting client's MAC address on node.js

Tags: node.js, mac-address

Is there a way to find client's mac address on Node.js? I have been searching about it and i found node-sigar project but it didn't works because it throws a "cannot find module ./build/Release/sigar" error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless your code is running on the same LAN segment as the client, you cannot obtain the MAC address of a client. You'd need to likely shell out to a command line tool or native support to gain addresses on the local LAN segment.

For nodejs: https://npmjs.org/search?q=Arp

If you try to get remote clients' MAC addresses, you'll end up with the address of a router more than likely.

Comment: If the code is running on the same LAN segment as the client, he can try something like [this](https://github.com/bcamarneiro/macfromip)

Answer (score -3):

The [getmac module](https://github.com/bevry/getmac) will do this.  It calls out to the command line to get the system's network config info and then uses a regex to parse output to find the mac address.  The system commands it uses are `getmac` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (other platforms).

Comment: getmac does not return the client's MAC Address (as was requested by the OP), it returns the local machine's MAC Address.