# Can mac address be fetched using node js and browserify?

Tags: node.js, browserify

Following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac) link I have created a file index.js with the script 'require(getmac)' and ran the command `browserify index.js > bundle.js`
The file bundle.js got created and I added the same in the script path `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`.Also I added the file bundle.js in the project but somehow everytime I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` whenever I load the page.

The error is in the line `isWindows = process.platform.indexOf('win') === 0;` in bundle.js .Going through the script in details I found out **process.platform** is undefined. Please follow the script to find the content of bundle.js

```js
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
// shim for using process in browser
var process = module.exports = {};

// cached from whatever global is present so that test runners that stub it
// don't break things.  But we need to wrap it in a try catch in case it is
// wrapped in strict mode code which doesn't define any globals.  It's inside a
// function because try/catches deoptimize in certain engines.

var cachedSetTimeout;
var cachedClearTimeout;

function defaultSetTimout() {
    throw new Error('setTimeout has not been defined');
}
function defaultClearTimeout () {
    throw new Error('clearTimeout has not been defined');
}
(function () {
    try {
        if (typeof setTimeout === 'function') {
            cachedSetTimeout = setTimeout;
        } else {
            cachedSetTimeout = defaultSetTimout;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        cachedSetTimeout = defaultSetTimout;
    }
    try {
        if (typeof clearTimeout === 'function') {
            cachedClearTimeout = clearTimeout;
        } else {
            cachedClearTimeout = defaultClearTimeout;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        cachedClearTimeout = defaultClearTimeout;
    }
} ())
function runTimeout(fun) {
    if (cachedSetTimeout === setTimeout) {
        //normal enviroments in sane situations
        return setTimeout(fun, 0);
    }
    // if setTimeout wasn't available but was latter defined
    if ((cachedSetTimeout === defaultSetTimout || !cachedSetTimeout) && setTimeout) {
        cachedSetTimeout = setTimeout;
        return setTimeout(fun, 0);
    }
    try {
        // when when somebody has screwed with setTimeout but no I.E. maddness
        return cachedSetTimeout(fun, 0);
    } catch(e){
        try {
            // When we are in I.E. but the script has been evaled so I.E. doesn't trust the global object when called normally
            return cachedSetTimeout.call(null, fun, 0);
        } catch(e){
            // same as above but when it's a version of I.E. that must have the global object for 'this', hopfully our context correct otherwise it will throw a global error
            return cachedSetTimeout.call(this, fun, 0);
        }
    }


}
function runClearTimeout(marker) {
    if (cachedClearTimeout === clearTimeout) {
        //normal enviroments in sane situations
        return clearTimeout(marker);
    }
    // if clearTimeout wasn't available but was latter defined
    if ((cachedClearTimeout === defaultClearTimeout || !cachedClearTimeout) && clearTimeout) {
        cachedClearTimeout = clearTimeout;
        return clearTimeout(marker);
    }
    try {
        // when when somebody has screwed with setTimeout but no I.E. maddness
        return cachedClearTimeout(marker);
    } catch (e){
        try {
            // When we are in I.E. but the script has been evaled so I.E. doesn't  trust the global object when called normally
            return cachedClearTimeout.call(null, marker);
        } catch (e){
            // same as above but when it's a version of I.E. that must have the global object for 'this', hopfully our context correct otherwise it will throw a global error.
            // Some versions of I.E. have different rules for clearTimeout vs setTimeout
            return cachedClearTimeout.call(this, marker);
        }
    }



}
var queue = [];
var draining = false;
var currentQueue;
var queueIndex = -1;

function cleanUpNextTick() {
    if (!draining || !currentQueue) {
        return;
    }
    draining = false;
    if (currentQueue.length) {
        queue = currentQueue.concat(queue);
    } else {
        queueIndex = -1;
    }
    if (queue.length) {
        drainQueue();
    }
}

function drainQueue() {
    if (draining) {
        return;
    }
    var timeout = runTimeout(cleanUpNextTick);
    draining = true;

    var len = queue.length;
    while(len) {
        currentQueue = queue;
        queue = [];
        while (++queueIndex < len) {
            if (currentQueue) {
                currentQueue[queueIndex].run();
            }
        }
        queueIndex = -1;
        len = queue.length;
    }
    currentQueue = null;
    draining = false;
    runClearTimeout(timeout);
}

process.nextTick = function (fun) {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length - 1);
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args[i - 1] = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    queue.push(new Item(fun, args));
    if (queue.length === 1 && !draining) {
        runTimeout(drainQueue);
    }
};

// v8 likes predictible objects
function Item(fun, array) {
    this.fun = fun;
    this.array = array;
}
Item.prototype.run = function () {
    this.fun.apply(null, this.array);
};
process.title = 'browser';
process.browser = true;
process.env = {};
process.argv = [];
process.version = ''; // empty string to avoid regexp issues
process.versions = {};

function noop() {}

process.on = noop;
process.addListener = noop;
process.once = noop;
process.off = noop;
process.removeListener = noop;
process.removeAllListeners = noop;
process.emit = noop;
process.prependListener = noop;
process.prependOnceListener = noop;

process.listeners = function (name) { return [] }

process.binding = function (name) {
    throw new Error('process.binding is not supported');
};

process.cwd = function () { return '/' };
process.chdir = function (dir) {
    throw new Error('process.chdir is not supported');
};
process.umask = function() { return 0; };

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
require('getmac')
},{"getmac":6}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var _slicedToArray = function () { function sliceIterator(arr, i) { var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"]) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; } return function (arr, i) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { return arr; } else if (Symbol.iterator in Object(arr)) { return sliceIterator(arr, i); } else { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); } }; }();

/* eslint no-cond-assign:0 */

// Import
var typeChecker = require('typechecker');

// Eachr
module.exports = function eachr(subject, callback) {
 // Handle
 if (typeChecker.isArray(subject)) {
  for (var key = 0; key < subject.length; ++key) {
   var value = subject[key];
   if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
    break;
   }
  }
 } else if (typeChecker.isPlainObject(subject)) {
  for (var _key in subject) {
   if (subject.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
    var _value = subject[_key];
    if (callback.call(subject, _value, _key, subject) === false) {
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 } else if (typeChecker.isMap(subject)) {
  var entries = subject.entries();
  var entry = void 0;while (entry = entries.next().value) {
   var _entry = entry;

   var _entry2 = _slicedToArray(_entry, 2);

   var _key2 = _entry2[0];
   var _value2 = _entry2[1]; // destructuring

   if (callback.call(subject, _value2, _key2, subject) === false) {
    break;
   }
  }
 } else {
  // Perhaps falling back to a `for of` loop here would be sensible
  throw new Error('eachr does not know how to iterate what was passed to it');
 }

 // Return
 return subject;
};
},{"typechecker":7}],5:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

// Import
var typeChecker = require('typechecker');
var eachr = require('eachr');

// Define
module.exports = function (opts, next) {
 var config = arguments.length <= 2 || arguments[2] === undefined ? {} : arguments[2];

 // Empty, set default
 if (config.completionCallbackNames == null) {
  config.completionCallbackNames = ['next'];
 }

 // Not array, make array
 else if (typeChecker.isArray(config.completionCallbackNames) === false) {
   config.completionCallbackNames = [config.completionCallbackNames];
  }

 // Arguments
 if (typeChecker.isFunction(opts) && next == null) {
  next = opts;
  opts = {};
 } else if (!opts) {
  opts = {};
 }

 // Completion callback
 if (!next) {
  // Cycle the completionCallbackNames to check if the completion callback name exists in opts
  // if it does, then use it as the next and delete it's value
  eachr(config.completionCallbackNames, function (completionCallbackName) {
   if (typeof opts[completionCallbackName] !== 'undefined') {
    next = opts[completionCallbackName];
    delete opts[completionCallbackName];
    return false; // break
    // ^ why this only does the first, and not all, using the last, I don't know ...
    // can be changed in a future major update
   }
  });
 }

 // Ensure
 if (!next) next = null;

 // Return
 return [opts, next];
};
},{"eachr":4,"typechecker":7}],6:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (process){
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
var exec, extractOptsAndCallback, getMac, isMac, isWindows, macRegex, zeroRegex;

exec = require('child_process').exec;

extractOptsAndCallback = require('extract-opts');

isWindows = process.platform.indexOf('win') === 0;

macRegex = /(?:[a-z0-9]{2}[:\-]){5}[a-z0-9]{2}/ig;

zeroRegex = /(?:[0]{2}[:\-]){5}[0]{2}/;

getMac = function(opts, next) {
  var command, data, extractMac, ref;
  ref = extractOptsAndCallback(opts, next), opts = ref[0], next = ref[1];
  data = opts.data;
  if (data == null) {
    data = null;
  }
  command = isWindows ? "getmac" : "ifconfig -a || ip link";
  extractMac = function(data, next) {
    var err, isZero, macAddress, match, result;
    result = null;
    while (match = macRegex.exec(data)) {
      macAddress = match[0];
      isZero = zeroRegex.test(macAddress);
      if (isZero === false) {
        if (result == null) {
          result = macAddress;
        }
      }
    }
    if (result === null) {
      err = new Error('could not determine the mac address from:\n' + data);
      return next(err);
    }
    return next(null, result);
  };
  if (data) {
    return extractMac(data, next);
  } else {
    return exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return extractMac(stdout, next);
    });
  }
};

isMac = function(macAddress) {
  var ref;
  return ((ref = String(macAddress).match(macRegex)) != null ? ref.length : void 0) === 1;
};

module.exports = {
  macRegex: macRegex,
  getMac: getMac,
  isMac: isMac
};

}).call(this,require('_process'))
},{"_process":2,"child_process":1,"extract-opts":5}],7:[function(require,module,exports){
/* @flow */
/* eslint quote-props:0 */
'use strict';

// Character positions

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

var INDEX_OF_FUNCTION_NAME = 9; // "function X", X is at index 9
var FIRST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII = 65; // A is at index 65 in ASCII
var LAST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII = 90; // Z is at index 90 in ASCII


// -----------------------------------
// Values

/**
 * Get the object type string
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {string}
 */
function getObjectType(value /* :mixed */) /* :string */{
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an object
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isObject(value /* :any */) /* :boolean */{
  // null is object, hence the extra check
  return value !== null && (typeof value === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(value)) === 'object';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an object and only an object
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isPlainObject(value /* :any */) /* :boolean */{
  /* eslint no-proto:0 */
  return isObject(value) && value.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is empty
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isEmpty(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return value == null;
}

/**
 * Is empty object
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isEmptyObject(value /* :Object */) /* :boolean */{
  // We could use Object.keys, but this is more effecient
  for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/**
 * Is ES6+ class
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNativeClass(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  // NOTE TO DEVELOPER: If any of this changes, isClass must also be updated
  return typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('class') === 0;
}

/**
 * Is Conventional Class
 * Looks for function with capital first letter MyClass
 * First letter is the 9th character
 * If changed, isClass must also be updated
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isConventionalClass(value /* :any */) /* :boolean */{
  if (typeof value !== 'function') return false;
  var c = value.toString().charCodeAt(INDEX_OF_FUNCTION_NAME);
  return c >= FIRST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII && c <= LAST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII;
}

// There use to be code here that checked for CoffeeScript's "function _Class" at index 0 (which was sound)
// But it would also check for Babel's __classCallCheck anywhere in the function, which wasn't sound
// as somewhere in the function, another class could be defined, which would provide a false positive
// So instead, proxied classes are ignored, as we can't guarantee their accuracy, would also be an ever growing set


// -----------------------------------
// Types

/**
 * Is Class
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isClass(value /* :any */) /* :boolean */{
  // NOTE TO DEVELOPER: If any of this changes, you may also need to update isNativeClass
  if (typeof value !== 'function') return false;
  var s = value.toString();
  if (s.indexOf('class') === 0) return true;
  var c = s.charCodeAt(INDEX_OF_FUNCTION_NAME);
  return c >= FIRST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII && c <= LAST_UPPERCASE_INDEX_IN_ASCII;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an error
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isError(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return value instanceof Error;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is a date
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isDate(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object Date]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an arguments object
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isArguments(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object Arguments]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is a function
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isFunction(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object Function]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an regex
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isRegExp(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object RegExp]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is an array
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isArray(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return typeof Array.isArray === 'function' && Array.isArray(value) || getObjectType(value) === '[object Array]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a valule is a number
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNumber(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return typeof value === 'number' || getObjectType(value) === '[object Number]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is a string
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isString(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return typeof value === 'string' || getObjectType(value) === '[object String]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a valule is a boolean
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isBoolean(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return value === true || value === false || getObjectType(value) === '[object Boolean]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is null
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNull(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return value === null;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is undefined
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isUndefined(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return typeof value === 'undefined';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is a Map
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isMap(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object Map]';
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a value is a WeakMap
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isWeakMap(value /* :mixed */) /* :boolean */{
  return getObjectType(value) === '[object WeakMap]';
}

// -----------------------------------
// General

/**
 * The type mapping (type => method) to use for getType. Frozen.
 */
var typeMap = Object.freeze({
  array: isArray,
  boolean: isBoolean,
  date: isDate,
  error: isError,
  class: isClass,
  function: isFunction,
  null: isNull,
  number: isNumber,
  regexp: isRegExp,
  string: isString,
  'undefined': isUndefined,
  map: isMap,
  weakmap: isWeakMap,
  object: isObject
});

/**
 * Get the type of the value in lowercase
 * @param {any} value
 * @param {Object} [customTypeMap] a custom type map (type => method) in case you have new types you wish to use
 * @returns {?string}
 */
function getType(value /* :mixed */) /* :?string */{
  var customTypeMap /* :Object */ = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : typeMap;

  // Cycle through our type map
  for (var key in customTypeMap) {
    if (customTypeMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (customTypeMap[key](value)) {
        return key;
      }
    }
  }

  // No type was successful
  return null;
}

// Export
module.exports = {
  getObjectType: getObjectType,
  isObject: isObject,
  isPlainObject: isPlainObject,
  isEmpty: isEmpty,
  isEmptyObject: isEmptyObject,
  isNativeClass: isNativeClass,
  isConventionalClass: isConventionalClass,
  isClass: isClass,
  isError: isError,
  isDate: isDate,
  isArguments: isArguments,
  isFunction: isFunction,
  isRegExp: isRegExp,
  isArray: isArray,
  isNumber: isNumber,
  isString: isString,
  isBoolean: isBoolean,
  isNull: isNull,
  isUndefined: isUndefined,
  isMap: isMap,
  isWeakMap: isWeakMap,
  typeMap: typeMap,
  getType: getType
};
},{}]},{},[3]);
```

Am I missing any steps or missing any file?Or is it possible to fetch mac address from browser using browserify?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647916/getting-clients-mac-address-on-node-js

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [get the mac address of the current machine with node js using getmac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16386371/6207775)

Comment: Hi See Dart and Ayushya,I have gone through the posts you guys have mentioned but I wanted to mention the details of my work.Also mentioned posts does not contain any informations regarding browserify.