# Finding device ID - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to find out the unique device ID (for tablet/laptop/Kiosk) just like we have IMEI number for mobile phones. I know there is a device api but it wont give the unique id of the device that is logged on. We have certain requirements to map certain plants based on device. Is it possible and how using SAP UI5 application?

Comment: What do you mean by "logged on"? Which platform is the app deployed to and which unique device ID do you mean (MAC address, ...)?

Comment: Is finding device type enough for your case?

Answer (score 0):

No solution, for JavaScript through the browser. There are solutions if it is installed as a native app (like with PhoneGap - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.5.0/phonegap/device/device.uuid.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get IMEI from browser, details are given before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser/32334257).
You can not get client MAC address if you are not in same network, details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647916/getting-clients-mac-address-on-node-js).
You can use device API with running your app in Fiori Client for getting IMEI.
Another option may be using device location for determining plantd.