# How can I get user/ client MAC address in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an API using Node Express and mongoDB. I want to get user's MAC address when they are using the given URL.

I used the following code but it returns the server's MAC address where the API runs. I want the different different MAC for various users.

ex :

user1 >> `http://localhost:5000/api/getMacAddress  //get user1's MAC address`

user2 >> `http://localhost:5000/api/getMacAddress  //get user2's MAC address`

```
var address = require('address');

address(function (err, addrs) {
    console.log(addrs.ip, addrs.ipv6, addrs.mac);
    // '192.168.0.2', 'fe80::7aca:39ff:feb0:e67d', '78:ca:39:b0:e6:7d'
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting client's MAC address on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647916/getting-clients-mac-address-on-node-js)

Comment: but there is no descriptions to implement that

Comment: Will this api will  be running in same local network of its users?

Comment: not in the local network. it will on shared server

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save macaddress

```
var macaddress = require('macaddress');
macaddress.one(function (err, mac) {
  console.log("Mac address for this host: %s", mac);  
});
```

or if you use interface

```
macaddress.one('awdl0', function (err, mac) {
  console.log("Mac address for awdl0: %s", mac);  
});
```

or if you want get all interface mcaddress

```
macaddress.all(function (err, all) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(all, null, 2));
});
```

check this for all doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macaddress)

Comment: this is only returns the server MAC address. but I want the user's MAC address